# Which statistical test should I use to assess the impact of a trial between subjects over time?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, variance, t-test

In the following table, I'd like to determine if yield is significantly impacted by pesticide application (applied in seasons 7-10) or if the difference between the control field (A) and trial field (B) already existed prior to the pesticide applications in seasons 1-6.  **What test would I use for this?**

Example data:

```
 Season Field    Type Pesticide_Applied Yield..lbs.
      1     A Control                 0         300
      1     B   Trial                 0         350
      2     A Control                 0         320
      2     B   Trial                 0         340
      3     A Control                 0         350
      3     B   Trial                 0         400
      4     A Control                 0         360
      4     B   Trial                 0         410
      5     A Control                 0         320
      5     B   Trial                 0         360
      6     A Control                 0         330
      6     B   Trial                 0         320
      7     A Control                 1         320
      7     B   Trial                 1         315
      8     A Control                 1         350
      8     B   Trial                 1         400
      9     A Control                 1         370
      9     B   Trial                 1         420
     10     A Control                 1         380
     10     B   Trial                 1         430
```

I'll be using R to conduct this analysis.